# Unable to call custom module using Python/C API

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

File structure:

```
Foo/
     list.so
     main.cpp
     list.cpp
     boost_wrapper.cpp
```

**main.cpp** code:

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "list.cpp"


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    PyObject *pimport;
    pimport=PyString_FromString("list");
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyImport_Import(pimport);
    /*PyRun_SimpleString("l=list.LinkedList()");
    PyRun_SimpleString("l.insert(\"N\", 9)");
    PyRun_SimpleString("l.display()");*/
    Py_Finalize();      
}
```

ERROR:

```
ImportError: No module named list
```

However if I run python from bash, I'm able to successfully import the module and use all functions defined. I've also tried to import using just PyRun_SimpleString with no avail.

I suspect the current working directory is invisible to the Python Interpreter called by Py_Initialize().

Comment: Why are you including `list.cpp` into `main.cpp`? How did you create `list.so`?

Comment: list.cpp contains the Linked List definition and functions.
list.so was created after writing a boost::python wrapper for list.cpp
And yes, import list works in IDLE, when I run it from the same directory.

Comment: Ok, I have a working solution; but I'm sure this is the worst implementation. [solution](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7745988/)

Comment: Maybe you need to prepend `.` to `sys.path`, after which `PyImport_Import` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines after `Py_Initialize();` to append your PYTHONPATH

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
```